# How do you copy an int or a char into a string element? I'm having trouble with pointers and casting

Tags: arrays, c, string, function, pointers

Instead of having the following function print out an encrypted version of each element in the string, I would like to pass each encrypted digit into a new string and then return a pointer to that new array.

```
void encrypt(int key, char *plaintext)
{
    int length = strlen(plaintext);

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        if isupper(plaintext[i])
            printf("%c", (((plaintext[i] + key) - 'A') % 26) + 'A');
        else if islower(plaintext[i])
            printf("%c", (((plaintext[i] + key) - 'a') % 26) + 'a');
        else
            printf("%c", plaintext[i]);
    }
}
```

I wrote the following function, but I get the following errors in clang:

Lines 12 & 14:

> incompatible integer to pointer conversion assigning to 'char *' from 'int'

Line 16:

> incompatible integer to pointer conversion assigning to 'char *' from 'char'; take the address with &

I'm new to pointers and can't figure out why my approach doesn't work. On lines 12 & 14, I've tried casting the result of the formula to a char to no avail.

```
char * encrypt(int key, char *plaintext)
{
    int length = strlen(plaintext);
    char *cipher[length];
    char element;
    
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        element = (char) &plaintext[i];

        if isupper(element)
            cipher[i] = (((element + key) - 'A') % 26) + 'A'; // Line 12 error
        else if islower(element)
            cipher[i] = (((element + key) - 'a') % 26) + 'a'; // Line 14 error
        else
            cipher[i] = element; // Line 16 error
    }

    return cipher[0];
}
```

Comment: The first code snippet you show don't even have 16 lines. What lines are the errors about? Please add comments on those lines. Also please copy-paste the *full* and *complete* build output into the question. Often there are other messages or informational notes that could be useful to see.

Comment: As for the second snippet, `&plaintext[i]` is a *pointer* to element `i` in the string. What you want is the element itself, which is just plain `plaintext[i]`.

Comment: And both snippets should be reporting more errors than you claim, since you have syntax errors for the conditions in the `if`. Please create a proper [mcve], one that you can build and replicate *only* the errors you ask about, and copy-paste it into the question.

Comment: `char *cipher[length]` : I think you made a mistake here. Choose either to work with a pointer to a `char` either with an array of characters. You declared `cipher` as an array of pointers to `char`. Remove the length from the declaration and use `malloc`.

Comment: You should allocate memory if you want to return it. You need to work to understand memory and pointer in C.

Comment: General rules: Don't try to use pointers until you know what you're doing, and try not to use explicit casts at all.  For an ordinary program like this one, if the compiler complains about a type mismatch, the fix is almost invariably that you need to change the type of something, *not* that you need to add an explicit cast somewhere.  (In this case, your problems are that you (a) unnecessarily generated an extra pointer when you wrote `element = &plaintext[i]` and (b) picked the wrong type for the `cipher` array.)

Answer (score 0):

> how do you copy an int or a char into a string element?

**Where to form the result?**

`char *cipher[length];` is an array of pointers, not the expected array of `char`.  Code like `cipher[i] = (((element + key) - 'A') % 26) + 'A';` is attempting to assigned an *integer* to a pointer.

This array ceases to exist at the end of the function and is not something to `return`.

Instead, consider passing in the destination:

```
// char * encrypt(int key, char *plaintext)
void encrypt(int key, const char *plaintext, char *cipher) {
  ...
     cipher[i] = (plaintext[i] - 'A' + key) % 26 + 'A';
}

// sample call
char plain[] = "Hello";
char cipher[sizeof plain];
int key = 1;
encrypt(key, plain, cipher)
```

**`'\0'` termination**

Append a *null character* to the destination

```
// after the loop
cipher[i] = '\0';
```

**Advanced: Reduce key**

With `int key`, trouble occurs when `key < 0` or is near `INT_MAX`.  Reduce it to [0...26) before the loop.

```
key %= 26;
if (key < 0) key += 26;
```

Tip: this allows decryption using the same function by calling with `-key`.

**Minor: Look for the *null character***

Simplify code, use the right type for array indexing to handle *long* strings.

```
//int length = strlen(plaintext);
...
// for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)

size_t i;
for (i = 0; plaintext[i] != '\0'; i++)
```

**Advanced: Other**

Only listed for reference, but not detailed.

- *locale*
- Non-ASCII
- negative `char`

Comment: You really helped me understand pointers with this detailed explanation. My function now works and I understand how pointers work and how to use them between functions. Thank you!

Comment: @746f6f72626f69 Good. Another important item: A pointer is not an array.  An array is not a pointer.